# Averaging a function over solid angle

Tags: integration, geometry, solid-angle

I am trying to average $r$ over the solid angle $\Omega$ in 3D. To start this I have expressed $r$ in terms of the angle $a$ and sides $x$ and $d$ in 2D with the help of the law of cosines:
$r = x*cos(a) + d \sqrt{(1-x^2/d^2 Sin^2(a))}$
or $r = \sqrt{x^2 + d^2 - 2xd* Cos(a)} $. The next step that I tried to take was $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} r da *\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}sin(\phi)d\phi$ to average over the solid angle $d\Omega = sin(\phi)d{\theta}d\phi$. This method gave me results in terms of elliptic integrals which is not what I was looking for. Is there a simpler (or completely different) method for doing averaging over the solid angle? Or should I reconsider my expressions for $r$? Thanks

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what angle $\phi$ represents and why you are taking a space average for a planar figure.

Comment: With $\phi$ I mean the zenith angle, also the figure is supposed to be 3D but I tried expressing $r$ in 2D

Comment: Knowing the original 3D setting would help. You should also correct ${1\over\pi}$ to ${1\over2}$ in your integral formula, but the integral over $\phi$ could be simply discarded: you are averaging over angle $a$.

Comment: In addition, your second formula for $r$ is wrong.

Comment: Treating $a$ as an azimuthal angle cannot be correct, because $a$ can only vary between $0$ and $\pi$. Hence I suspect, even without knowing the setting in space, that you should simply regard $a$ as the zenith angle.

Comment: Yes sorry, for the second $r$ formula I have change the angle $a$ to be in between $x$ and $d$. For the physical context: I am trying to express the distance between the center of the Milky Way to another galaxy, $r$, in terms of the distance between the center of the MW to our sun, $x$, and angle $a$. This is why I would want it to work for any angle between 0 and 2$\pi$.

Comment: If $a\ge\pi$ your triangle doesn't exist and you formulas don't work. The only meaningful (and natural) way to proceed is that of considering $a$ as the zenith angle, while ray $r$ can rotate around $x$ of an azimuthal angle $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Of course your computation is only a waist of time if $d\gg x$, which is the case for most galaxies out there. In other words: your work is useful only if you are considering a galaxy in the Local Group.